# How to make the dropDown in a UITableViewCell clickable without clickin the next cell and without adjusting the height of the cell?

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, uitableview, tableview, cell

I have DropDown class (the custom dropDown menu which is a tableViewController)

It is working (tested and used in other classes)

Then I have a PersonalInfo Class..

my PersonalInfo class is a TableViewController containing custom cells

Each cell has a UIView dropDownView and a textField contentTextField.

making the DropDown a subview of dropDownView, I'm able to make the dropDown menu appear on each cell. However, when the dropDown goes beyond the height of the cell, the dropDown items  are not clickable anymore but they're still visible.

If i make the cell's height larger it works fine, but I want to keep the cell's height at a certain size.
I tried bringing views to front, never worked. 
Can anybody help me? I'm running out of ideas.. 
thanks

Comment: Did you add your drop down menu as a sub view of your cell, or add it to the contentView of the cell?

Comment: yup i did add it... i'll just try da_h-man's suggestion thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the drop-down being a subview to your cell, you can only control the content within that cell (I think...). From an "Apple Human Interface Design Guide" perspective, your approach is probably a bit unusual.

Firstly, you wouldn't really need every single cell to have a drop down, right? I mean, even if you have a drop-down menu *within* a cell, you'd only display one drop down at a time, and not multiple ones. So you could make the drop down a sub-view of the table. Or, more aligned with the standard approach, you would have a drill-down view that loads the drop-down / subtable into the current table, similar to all the tutorials on table views.

Hope this helps,

da_h-man